# Forms not saving

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, save

Firstly, I apologise for my terminology and sometimes stupidity, as I am completely self/internet (mostly on here) taught. I've been developing an app for the past few years, mostly to help me with work, and more for kicks and giggles. I have now run into a problem that has me stumped! So I am calling out for any suggestions please :)

Okay, some background, I use colours on all forms to identify blocks of data based on an ID - it looks pretty, okay; and sometimes it's a quick identifier of which block the data belongs to when skimming through tables. So I have a form where I or the user can change these colours to whatever suits their eyes, needs etc. and there is a table that holds this information. Now these colours are applied using the 'Conditional Formatting' (when ID = 1 then background this colour, font that colour, etc). When a Form is opened in the FormLoad() code there is a check to see if the colours have been changed and if so then a module is called which updates all the 'Conditional Formats' on the Form (I should add here that it's only applied to the tables on the form), and everything looks pretty and more important works! Now this process is relatively slow (a couple of seconds on some forms), too slow to run every time the form is opened. So ages ago I found a way to force Access to save the design, including the 'Conditional Formatting':

```
DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdDesignView)
Forms!PrePlanner!BtnHelp.Caption = "Help"
DoCmd.Save acForm, "PrePlanner"
DoCmd.Close acForm, "PrePlanner", acSaveYes
```

This works perfectly on some forms but not on other!!

At first I thought it was something to do with the subForms, as it WASN'T working on all the forms that have subForms and the ones it was working on had no subForms... So I copied one of a simple subForms (a recently created form) which can open as a normal form, made changes to the colours opened the TEST form, the colours updated as expected, closed the form with the above code and the Formatting WASN'T saved! :( (If I change the Help Button to say "Help!" this change IS saved)

The Forms that don't save with the above code are also the most recent Forms that I have designed, the ones that do save are older forms (a couple years old and designed on a different computer but the same version of Access). I copied one of these older Forms, changed the colours, etc etc and this it DID save!!!

I've been through and compared all the properties of a working form and a nonworking form and nothing, I've tried exporting and importing... Please any thoughts would really help my sanity!!

Thanks in advance

....I forgot to say that I'm using Access 2016 on a 64bit Windows 10 machine.

*Additional Info.*

Having played around this morning, I created a new form (from scratch) configured the records so that the Conditional Formatting can be applied, etc. Opened the new form the Conditional Formatting was updated, the form closed and saved. Upon reopening the new form everything was as it should be the Conditional Formatting was saved. So I then add a subForm, and tried again, the Conditional Formatting was updated, the from closed BUT this time without saving the Conditional Formatting!! I then removed the subForm and repeated the test, this time the Conditional Formatting was saved.

So it seems to be something to do with subForms, what changes to the form properties does adding a subForm trigger that would stop the Conditional Formatting from being saved? Is this a quirk in Access?

Thanks again.

Comment: Break through, I still have to test it but it looks promising, I tried what you suggested, Opened the Forms in Design View, make the changes, SAVE it and then close it (The Save on close seems to be the issue). Then reopen it in Normal View... I just worked on a test form so fingers crossed!!! Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried running your code to apply the formatting while the form is in design view? It seems like conditional formatting and properties don't save when updated via VBA while the form is in normal view mode. I've had good luck reopening the form in design, running the code, and then saving the form.

Comment: Thanks; I have just given your idea a go... Nope the conditional formatting is still not saved :(